# Error importing SBT project in IntelliJ / no src folder appears

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm new to working with both IntelliJ and Scala, so I've been trying to set up a basic HelloWorld project using it. However once I try to load the project I'm met with two problems

1. I get an error saying there was an "Error while importing SBT project"
2. No 'src' folder appears on the project tree

I've seen similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767463/intellij-14-create-import-a-scala-sbt-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722048/intellij-idea-13-new-scala-sbt-project-hasnt-src-directory-structure-generated), but I still can't get the project to load properly.

For some reason this site doesn't let you post an image until you have 10 reputation, so here is a link to the error message I'm receiving [http://i.imgur.com/vDZB6SA.png](https://i.imgur.com/vDZB6SA.png).

From the looks of it, it seems like it's unable to download the necessary dependencies, however I was able to download the scala plugin earlier, so I can't see why there would be a problem now.

I tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860940/where-can-i-set-proxy-for-sbt-in-intellij-idea) on updating the proxy settings, but that doesn't work either.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? I'm really stuck here on how to proceed.

EDIT 1:

Details on IntelliJ

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3
Build #IC-162.1812.17, built on August 30, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_65-b17 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Setting up the proejct:

I just followed an example and went to New Project > Scala > SBT > name project and finish. Then once it loads I get the error displayed in the picture above. The SBT version is 0.13.8 and the Scala version is 2.11.8

Comment: Re: not allowing posting images. Error messages are just text, why not just copy-paste the text here?

Comment: @Esko Unless they're short error messages, I personally feel like they just clutter up the body of the message and make it more difficult to read. Posting a screenshot is just nicer IMO

Comment: well - welcome to StackOverflow where we absolutely **love** questions with full context in them! :) Just add triple backticks (`), four spaces or > to turn it into somewhat indented/stylized.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) can you share how you set up the project in IntelliJ, and what version are you using? Might want to check that the project type you created is not a generic project, but a Scala or Java project.

Comment: Hi @AndrewC. I've updated my question with more information on the project details. Anything of use to you there?

Comment: @Eoin I understand your problem a bit better now. First, have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062570/configuring-intellij-idea-15-0-4-and-sbt-0-13-7-with-local-artifactory-server/36072643)? Clearing sbt repositories and rebuilding anew may help. Second, beware that IntelliJ will download and manage a different install of scala and sbt than you might have installed previously on your system (I am experiencing this on OSX with homebrew). Can you simply run `sbt` from your console and let it download its dependencies that way? If so, that narrows the problem to IntelliJ.

Comment: @AndrewC. I think I've managed to identify the problem. While I had tried to change the proxy settings in IntelliJ before, I was apparently missing some of the necessary details. After updating the proxy information, it appears that everything is working fine, for now at least. If the problems arises again, I may be back for more advice :)

Comment: @Eoin Glad to hear you got it working. Posting an answer with the details on what you did to resolve the proxy issue would be a good follow-up for anyone who runs across this in the future. Best of luck going forward with Scala!